# Any method to avoid html code duplication?

Tags: php, html

Considering the two page designs are very similar, is there a way to reuse html snippets between the two pages, or some other method to avoid html code duplication?

Comment: You can make use of template based design. There are multiple way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at php include for php pages or I like to use css.min.js for html pages - (I cant remember who developed it I will try and find out - but it is free to use)

I use the code like this to include a menu of html links:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="csi.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Testing Javascript
<br>
<div data-include="checkout_01.html"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

checkout_01 is the html file i want to include - normally I would put the html to include in a 'include' folder and reference it with

```
<div data-include="include/checkout_01.html"></div>
```

Then if I want to amend the menu of links i just change the one file and it changes on all pages

... found the link - https://github.com/LexmarkWeb/csi.js - obviously you can use csi.min.js or csi.js provided you download the one you want to use